Spring Batch issue with MultiResourceItemWriter and ClassifierCompositeItemWriter
I am using Spring Boot + Batch v2.7.1 in my project and looks like there is a bug when Reading from FlatFileItemReader using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter and MultiResourceItemWriter as itemCountLimitPerResource value doesn't works well and gives wrong responses.
I am reading csv file and splitting into multiple files having max records in every file should be 5 only, but the code which I developed giving me 7 values.
MainApp.java
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MultiResourceSplitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultiResourceSplitApplication.class, args);
    }
}

MyJob.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.builder.ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

@Configuration
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> itemReader() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames("empId", "firstName", "lastName", "role");

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> employeeLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        employeeLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        employeeLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new EmployeeFieldSetMapper());
        employeeLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("flatFileReader")
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("employee.csv"))
                .lineMapper(employeeLineMapper)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Employee> classifierCompositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
        Classifier<Employee, ItemWriter<? super Employee>> classifier = new EmployeeClassifier(
                javaDeveloperItemWriter(), 
                pythonDeveloperItemWriter(), 
                cloudDeveloperItemWriter());
        
        return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .classifier(classifier)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> javaDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw1")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("javaDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("javaDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> pythonDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw2")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("pythonDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("pythonDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> cloudDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw3")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("cloudDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("cloudDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }
}

Classifier.java
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;

import lombok.Setter;


@Setter
public class EmployeeClassifier implements Classifier<Employee, ItemWriter<? super Employee>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ItemWriter<Employee> javaDeveloperFileItemWriter;
    private ItemWriter<Employee> pythonDeveloperFileItemWriter;
    private ItemWriter<Employee> cloudDeveloperFileItemWriter;
    
    public EmployeeClassifier() {
        
    }

    public EmployeeClassifier(ItemWriter<Employee> javaDeveloperFileItemWriter,
                              ItemWriter<Employee> pythonDeveloperFileItemWriter,
                              ItemWriter<Employee> cloudDeveloperFileItemWriter) {
        this.javaDeveloperFileItemWriter = javaDeveloperFileItemWriter;
        this.pythonDeveloperFileItemWriter = pythonDeveloperFileItemWriter;
        this.cloudDeveloperFileItemWriter = cloudDeveloperFileItemWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<? super Employee> classify(Employee employee) {
        if(employee.getRole().equals("Java Developer")){
            return javaDeveloperFileItemWriter;
        }
        else if(employee.getRole().equals("Python Developer")){
            return pythonDeveloperFileItemWriter;
        }
        return cloudDeveloperFileItemWriter;
    }
}

Employee.java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private String empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return empId + "," + firstName + "," + lastName + "," + role;
    }
}

EmployeeFieldSetMapper.java
public class EmployeeFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        return Employee.builder()
                .empId(fieldSet.readRawString("empId"))
                .firstName(fieldSet.readRawString("firstName"))
                .lastName(fieldSet.readRawString("lastName"))
                .role(fieldSet.readRawString("role"))
                .build();
    }
}

employee.csv
empId,firstName,lastName,role
1,Mike ,Doe,Java Developer
2,Matt ,Doe,Java Developer
3,Deepak ,Doe,Python Developer
4,Neha ,Doe,Python Developer
5,Harish,Doe,Python Developer
6,Parag ,Doe,Python Developer
7,Harshita ,Doe,Python Developer
8,Pranali ,Doe,Python Developer
9,Raj ,Doe,Python Developer
10,Ravi,Doe,Python Developer
11,Gagan,Doe,Java Developer
12,Ashish ,Doe,Java Developer
13,Rajesh,Doe,Java Developer
14,Anosh ,Doe,Java Developer
15,Arpit ,Doe,Java Developer
16,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer
17,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer

Output:
javaDeveloper-employee.csv-1
1,Mike ,Doe,Java Developer
2,Matt ,Doe,Java Developer
11,Gagan,Doe,Java Developer
12,Ashish ,Doe,Java Developer
13,Rajesh,Doe,Java Developer
14,Anosh ,Doe,Java Developer
15,Arpit ,Doe,Java Developer

javaDeveloper-employee.csv-2
16,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer
17,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer

pythonDeveloper-employee.csv-1
3,Deepak ,Doe,Python Developer
4,Neha ,Doe,Python Developer
5,Harish,Doe,Python Developer
6,Parag ,Doe,Python Developer
7,Harshita ,Doe,Python Developer
8,Pranali ,Doe,Python Developer
9,Raj ,Doe,Python Developer

pythonDeveloper-employee.csv-1
10,Ravi,Doe,Python Developer


Finally, found the issue.
Root cause: Usage of both .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3) & .itemCountLimitPerResource(5) were not working together to give the appropriate and expected records in your case.
That's why the POC was not working.

Note: You don't need to have .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3) as you are using .itemCountLimitPerResource(5) . itemCountLimitPerResource method will take care of creating the chunk and put at most 5 records in every file.
Fix/Solution: Make .<Employee, Employee>chunk(0) in the MyJobConfig class.
Updated MyJobConfig:
@Configuration
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> itemReader() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames("empId", "firstName", "lastName", "role");

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> employeeLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        employeeLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        employeeLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new EmployeeFieldSetMapper());
        employeeLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("flatFileReader")
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("employee.csv"))
                .lineMapper(employeeLineMapper)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Employee> classifierCompositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
        Classifier<Employee, ItemWriter<? super Employee>> classifier = new EmployeeClassifier(
                javaDeveloperItemWriter(),
                pythonDeveloperItemWriter(),
                cloudDeveloperItemWriter());

        return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .classifier(classifier)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> javaDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw1")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("javaDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("/users/anisb/bounty-folder/javaDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> pythonDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw2")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("pythonDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("/users/anisb/bounty-folder/pythonDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Employee> cloudDeveloperItemWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .name("iw3")
                .build();

        return new MultiResourceItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("cloudDeveloperItemWriter")
                .delegate(itemWriter)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("/users/anisb/bounty-folder/cloudDeveloper-employee.csv"))
                .itemCountLimitPerResource(5)
                .resourceSuffixCreator(index -> "-" + index)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(0)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }
}

Tested on my local:

javaDeveloper-employee.csv-1
1,Mike ,Doe,Java Developer
2,Matt ,Doe,Java Developer
11,Gagan,Doe,Java Developer
12,Ashish ,Doe,Java Developer
13,Rajesh,Doe,Java Developer

javaDeveloper-employee.csv-2:
14,Anosh ,Doe,Java Developer
15,Arpit ,Doe,Java Developer
16,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer
17,Sneha ,Doe,Java Developer

pythonDeveloper-employee.csv-1:
3,Deepak ,Doe,Python Developer
4,Neha ,Doe,Python Developer
5,Harish,Doe,Python Developer
6,Parag ,Doe,Python Developer
7,Harshita ,Doe,Python Developer

pythonDeveloper-employee.csv-2:
8,Pranali ,Doe,Python Developer
9,Raj ,Doe,Python Developer
10,Ravi,Doe,Python Developer


Thanks. Do you've reference to official documentation pls? When I checked with the Spring xml beans based appraoch .. doesn't work..

@PAA I don't have an official documentation yet. XML based should also work in the same way. Java Based Configuration is no different from the Spring XML based.

Performance is such a poor this zero chunk size.

Although its working - I dont see this as a good solution

@PAA You don't want to have chunk 0 right?

We need to understand how records are getting read with chunk size = 0? I saw this in MultiresourceItemWriter doc - Note that new resources are created only at chunk boundaries i.e. the number of items written into one resource is between the limit set by setItemCountLimitPerResource(int) and (limit + chunk size).

@PAA when you have chunk 0, this means number of items to be written to file will be 5 (ItemCountLimitPerResource) and chunk will have no effect. Do you want to have chunk also?

If we keep chunk size, then the issue comes, thats why raised issue.. isn't it?

@PAA Yes I know. Just wanted to double check. As you had chunk size as 3 and ItemCountLimitPerResource is 5 and then the number of items written into one resource is between the limit set by setItemCountLimitPerResource(5) and (8) as per docs.

@PAA Can I know where it's causing a performance issue?

please take a huge file 500MB test it yourself

@PAA Okay. Let me check.

This seems like a bug in Spring Batch to me. The itemCountLimitPerResource should not be exceeded. Please open an issue with a minimal complete example and I will debug the case. Thank you.

I have raise a bug here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4660. Could you please have a look as its impacted us.

Is there any update on this please?

I already gave an update on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4660#issuecomment-2363345942: "I will plan the fix in a future patch release, because as of now we are working on the upcoming 5.2. If someone manages to fix the issue, then a PR is welcome."
